# Error when installing node.js on ubuntu 12.04- "Project not configured (run 'waf configure' first) "

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, installation, waf

So I'm following a node.js installation process (from a repository) with the following basic steps.

1. git clone https://github.com/joyent/node.git
2. cd node
3. git checkout v0.6.16 #Try checking nodejs.org for what the stable version is
4. ./configure
5. make
6. sudo make install

After trying to run the Makefile in the command line (typing make.), I get the following error that I don't know how to fix.

**Project not configured (run 'waf configure' first) error.  make:**  [program] Error 1
*

I'm trying to do this on ubuntu 12.04. 
Googled for this problem and haven't seen any resolutions. Not looking for a terse response. I'd like specific instructions on how to fix the problem. I appreciate the help and if you give a good response, I'll rate you up!

Comment: I assume there was an error during the "./configure" step...

Comment: Heres the output from the command line                   /home/student/node/wscript:374: error: Could not autodetect OpenSSL support. Make sure OpenSSL development packages are installed. Use configure --without-ssl to disable this message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the OpenSSL headers for compiling node.js:

- To compile without SSL support: Follow all steps from above, but configure with `./configure --without-ssl`
- Install SSL development packages before configure: `sudo apt-get install libssl-dev`

Comment: Just like terminal said haha wow that was stupid of me. Thanks!