# Project not configured (run 'waf configure' first) Makefile:11: recipe for target `program' failed

Tags: node.js

I have been trying to get node.js running on my windows machine(using cygwin). I have been running into this error and i am not sure what I am doing wrong. I am running the following commands-

1. git clone https://github.com/joyent/node.git nodejs
2. cd nodejs
3. git checkout v0.4.12~
4. ./configure
5. make
6. make install

However when i run the 'make' command, I am getting this:

Project not configured (run 'waf configure' first)
Makefile:11: recipe for target `program' failed
make: *** [program] Error 1

I have scoured a lot of places to fix this but haven't found anything relevant. I dont believe that this issue is the same as the one on [Error when installing node.js on ubuntu 12.04- "Project not configured (run 'waf configure' first) "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10690602/error-when-installing-node-js-on-ubuntu-12-04-project-not-configured-run-waf) because i have the open ssl packages.

Your help is deeply appreciated! Thanks!